# Определенное количество столбцов из файла CSV для графика

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

Как сделать график, который вытаскивает из файла CSV только определенное количество столбцов? Сейчас он вытаскивает все столбцы в непонятный график.

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\kiber\PycharmProjects\untitled14\troinik.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", index_col=5)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

[Ссылка на CSV файл](https://transfiles.ru/vj2u9)

Comment: Каким образом график может что-то откуда-то вытащить?

Comment: он должен выглядить примерно так:https://yandex.ru/images/search?pos=77&from=tabbar&p=1&img_url=https%3A%2F%2F4analytics.ru%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FFAQ%2F2_4_grafiki%2F2_4_grafik_4.jpg&text=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA&rpt=simage

Comment: Не скачивается.

Comment: некоторые столбцы нулевые

Comment: а какие столбцы вы хотите использовать?

Comment: @kiber чем тот ответ, который я привёл не подходит? Замените названия столбцов на Ваши

Comment: хорошо попробую

Comment: мне нужно именно работать с несколькими столбцами одновременно

Comment: S_troynik, Ex, Ey, P это столбцы которые я хочу использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас величины отличаются на ~13 порядков, поэтому график будет сильно сглажен...

Поэтому лучше сделать так:

```
cols = ["ModelingTime", "S_troynik", "Ex", "Ey", "P"]
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\troinik.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", 
                 usecols=cols, index_col="ModelingTime")
df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 8), sharex=True)
plt.show()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему не работает?
вот код: `import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ["ModelingTime", "S_troynik", "Ex", "Ey", "P"]
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\kiber\PycharmProjects\untitled14\troinik.csv", sep=";", decimal=",",
                 usecols=cols, index_col="ModelingTime")
df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 8), sharex=True)
plt.plot()`

Comment: @kiber, у меня - работает

Comment: просто забыл добавить plt.show()

Answer (score 1):

Нарисовать график не сложно:

```
cols = ["ModelingTime", "S_troynik", "Ex", "Ey", "P"]
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\troinik.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", 
                 usecols=cols, index_col="ModelingTime")
df.plot()
```

вот только результат вас врядли удовлетворит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у вас величины отличаются на ~13 порядков, поэтому график будет сильно сглажен...

Comment: а есть какой нибудь другой способ что-бы график не сглаживался?

Comment: @kiber, есть, и я его показал на втором графике

Comment: я наверно тупой но куда вы поставили строку из второго способа?

Comment: `df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 8), sharex=True)` - сразу под словами `Лучше сделать так:`

Comment: нет смысле в коде куда эту строку?

Comment: добавил отдельным ответом

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\kiber\PycharmProjects\untitled14\troinik.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", index_col=5)
plt.plot(df['x'].values, df['y'].values)
plt.show()
```